# Regex matching word that is in the middle of any character except a letter

Tags: java, regex

I'd like to know how to detect word that is between any characters except a letter from alphabet. I need this, because I'm working on a custom import organizer for Java. This is what I have already tried:

The regex expression:

```
[^(a-zA-Z)]InitializationEvent[^(a-zA-Z)]
```

I'm searching for the word "InitializationEvent".

The code snippet I've been testing on:

```
public void load(InitializationEvent event) {
```

It looks like adding space before the word helps... is the parenthesis inside of alphabet range?

I tested this in my program and it didn't work. Also I checked it on regexr.com, showing same results - class name not recognized.

Am I doing something wrong? I'm new to regex, so it might be a really basic mistake, or not. Let me know!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lose the parentheses:

```
[^a-zA-Z]InitializationEvent[^a-zA-Z]
```

Inside `[]`, parentheses are taken literally, and by inverting the group (`^`) you prevent it from matching because a `(` is preceding `InitializationEvent` in your string.

Note, however, that the above regex will only match if `InitializationEvent` is **neither** at the beginning **nor** at the end of the tested string. To allow that, you can use:

```
(^|[^a-zA-Z])InitializationEvent([^a-zA-Z]|$)
```

Or, without creating any matching groups (which is supposed to be cleaner, and perform better):

```
(?:^|[^a-zA-Z])InitializationEvent(?:[^a-zA-Z]|$)
```

Comment: This will fail to match if input is just `InitializationEvent`

Comment: @anubhava Not sure if the OP wants that or not, but you have a good point. I'll extend my answer.

Comment: Seems to solve my problem... It seems to perform about 15% faster then Zachs answer, so I marked this as the new best answer.

Answer (score 3):

> how to detect word that is between any characters except a letter from alphabet

This is the case where [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) come handy. You can use:

```
(?<![a-zA-Z])InitializationEvent(?![a-zA-Z])
```

- `(?<![a-zA-Z])` is negative lookbehind to assert that there is no alphabet at previous position
- `(?![a-zA-Z])` is negative lookahead to assert that there is no alphabet at next position

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gA0iD0/1)

Comment: It is not really a overkill for these requirements. All other answers posted will fail to match if input is just `InitializationEvent`

Answer (score 1):

You seem really close:

```
[^(a-zA-Z)]*(InitializationEvent)[^(a-zA-Z)]*
```

I think this is what you are looking for. The asterisk provides a match for zero or many of the character or group before it.

EDIT/UPDATE

My apologies on the initial response.

```
[^a-zA-Z]+(InitializationEvent)[^a-zA-Z]+
```

My regex is a little rusty, but this will match on any non-alphabet character one or many times prior to the InitializationEvent and after.

Comment: `*` defeats the purpose though, as it can mean "zero times", so the regex will also match `aaaInitializationEventaaa`.

Comment: @Siguza I just tested it, you're wrong. He's negating all of the characters

Comment: @m_callens Just look at the link I provided. Or [debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/LCpuJut53Pr_Al5F). Or [regexr](http://regexr.com/3dmmj). They all seem to prove you wrong.

Comment: Yes, he's negating the characters, but `(anything)*` also matches _nothing_, so `(anything)*xyz(anything)*` also matches `xyz`, which is a substring of `aaaxyzaaa`.

Comment: Ah! i see what you're saying. It seemed like you meant it would match the entire string `aaaInitializationEventaaa`.

Comment: Yes, sorry about this. Does this work better? 
` [^a-zA-Z]+(InitializationEvent)[^a-zA-Z]+`

Comment: @ZachLobato That should work, but it would work just as well without the `+`, as far as I can see. You'd arrive at the content of my original answer then, which had the problem of not matching `InitializationEvent` if it was at the very beginning or the very end of the tested string... which one can fix by `|`-ing in `^` and `$`.

Comment: This seems to work in my case, since i don't need the exact text to be matched, instead only recognized... However, what would the regex be in case I'd need to only match the text that wouldn't be in between 2 characters of alphabet?

Answer (score 1):

The parentheses are causing the problem, just skip them:

```
"[^a-zA-Z]InitializationEvent[^a-zA-Z]"
```

or use the predefined non-word character class which is slightly different because it also excludes numbers and the underscore:

```
 "\\WInitializationEvent\\W"
```

But as it seems you want to match a class name, this might be ok because the remaining character are exactly those that are allowed in a class name.

Comment: I don't think `\\W` will work because OP just wants to exclude letters from alphabet, whereas \\W will exclude numbers and underscore

Comment: Okay I see where I got it wrong now, \\W looks like a good choice, since I need to detect if class is used in code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about your application but from a regexp perspective you can use negative lookaheads and negative lookbehinds to define what cannot surround the String to specify a match.

I have added the negative lookahead `(?![a-zA-Z])` and the negative lookbehind `(?<![a-zA-Z])` in place of your `[^(a-zA-Z)]` originally supplied to create: `(?<![a-zA-Z])InitializationEvent(?![a-zA-Z])`

Quick Fiddle I created:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){
    String pattern = "(?<![a-zA-Z])InitializationEvent(?![a-zA-Z])";
    String sourceString = "public void load(InitializationEvent event) {";
    String sourceString2 = "public void load(BInitializationEventA event) {";

    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

    Matcher m = r.matcher(sourceString);
  if (m.find( )) {
     System.out.println("Found value of pattern in sourceString: " + m.group(0) );
  } else {
     System.out.println("NO MATCH in sourceString");
  }

   Matcher m2 = r.matcher(sourceString2);
  if (m2.find( )) {
     System.out.println("Found value of pattern in sourceString2: " + m2.group(0) );
  } else {
     System.out.println("NO MATCH in sourceString2");
  }
 }
```

}

output:

> sh-4.3$ java -Xmx128M -Xms16M HelloWorld
>   Found value of pattern in sourceString: InitializationEvent
>   NO MATCH in sourceString2

Comment: anubhava beat me to it while I was fiddling :P

Comment: I find this answer very good, since I was only working with regex in a "shitty" way - never used matchers and patterns (I did it using split method and then checking if length of the array it gives is bigger then 1).